# mod_rewrite on domain root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to find the correct mod_rewrite code for the following case:

```
domain.de => www.domain.com/de/
domain.de/... => www.domain.com/...
www.domain.de => www.domain.com/de/
www.domain.de/... => www.domain.com/...

domain.com => www.domain.com/en/
domain.com/... => www.domain.com/...
www.domain.com => www.domain.com/en/
www.domain.com/... => www.domain.com/...
```

so basically

1. all non-www domains should be redirect to www.
2. all uri's ending on .de or .de/ should be redirected to www.domain.**com**/de/
3. but if somebody enters something after the .de/ that should be simply appended to www.domain.com/...

Can anyone think of a clever solution for this? I have been struggling with {REQUEST_URI} and {REQUEST_FILENAME} trying to figure out if the requested URI ends on .de or .de/ but couldn't find a working solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.de$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/de/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.de$
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule . http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hi gumbo, thanks! that is exactly what i was looking for. can you tell me what the difference between ^$ and . in the rewriterule is?

Comment: `^$` matches just the URL path `/` while `.` matches anything else (`/` plus more). This is because when mod_rewrite is used in a .htaccess file, the per-directory path prefix is removed before testing and appended after applying a rule. And the path prefix of the root directory is `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Check some examples here:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml

and here:
http://howto.kryl.info/mod_rewrite/

to start:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.de$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/de/$1 [R=301,L]

etc